# How do I get MS Access 2007 to calculate row percentages?

Tags: ms-access-2007

How do I write a query in MS Access 2007 that displays both the count AND the percentage of the total records in a table for each row in a specified field?

For instance, if my table has a field called "gender," what is the query I should write to see the row count and percentage of Men and the row count and percentage of Women?

So, if the table had 1000 records, the result would look something like:

```
Men.....600.....60%
Women...400.....40%
```

I can easily write a query that just gives me the row count, but I can't figure out how to also see the percentages.

I should mention that I do not know SQL. I use the Design View when creating queries. But if you can give me the text for the query in SQL, I can copy and paste it into a new query and then save it.

Comment: consider using windowing functions - http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/working-with-window-functions-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

It's not part of SQL itself, but you can use a VBA function in a query to count the amount of records in a table: DCount ([MSDN](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dcount-function-HA001228817.aspx)).

Copy and paste the following lines in the query designer (top row, one line per column):

```
    TotalMen: DCount("*";"[TableNameHere]";"[Gender]='Male'")
    TotalWomen: DCount("*";"[TableNameHere]";"[Gender]='Female'")
```

You can then get the percentage by performing some simple math on the return values (again one line per column):

```
    TotalPersons: [TotalMen]+[TotalWomen]
    PercentageMen: [TotalMen]/[TotalPersons]
    PercentageWomen: [TotalWomen]/[TotalPersons]
```

Don't forget to set the format to Percentage or the values will show up as 0,6 and 0,4 instead of 60% and 40%.

By the way, there are probably more consise ways to do it. I tried to make it readable.

PS: don't forget to replace the names of the tables and fields.